# angular js formatted input not saving new value

Tags: angularjs

hi I have the following directive to validate and reformat the ssn#.
All works well except when I hit the 'save' button it never updates the $scope. Any help?
the following is the code for the directive"

```
app.directive('validateSsn', function () {
    var SSN_REGEXP = /^(?!000)(?!666)(?!9)\d{3}[- ]?(?!00)\d{2}[- ]?(?!0000)\d{4}$/;
    var ssnPattern = {
        3: '-',
        5: '-'
    };
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            var formatSSN = function () {
                var sTempString = ctrl.$viewValue;
                sTempString = sTempString.replace(/\-/g, '');
                var numbers = sTempString;
                temp = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                    temp += (ssnPattern[i] || '') + numbers[i];
                }
                ctrl.$viewValue = temp;
                elem.val(ctrl.$viewValue);
            };
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
                // test and set the validity after update.
                var valid = SSN_REGEXP.test(value);
                ctrl.$setValidity('ssnValid', valid);
            });
            // This runs when we update the text field
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('ssnValid', valid);
                return viewValue;
            });
            elem.bind('blur', formatSSN);

        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working:

http://jsfiddle.net/10thfloor/8BRp4/8/ (code from fiddle below)

Using elem.val() to set the input val? Looks like we have to manually feed that action into the '$digest' er.

Credit: @Jim:
"More to the point, any time you want to interact with $scope from within a DOM event, you'll need to use $scope.$apply"

```
<div>
    <legend>SSN:</legend>
    <form name="form" novalidate>
        <input type="text" ng-model="ssn" name="ssn" validate-ssn/>
        <br /> <span ng-show="form.ssn.$error.ssnValid">This is not valid SSN!</span>
    </form>
    unformatted: {{ssn}}
</div>
```

.

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('ssnApp', []);

app.directive('validateSsn', function () {
    var SSN_REGEXP = /^(?!000)(?!666)(?!9)\d{3}[- ]?(?!00)\d{2}[- ]?(?!0000)\d{4}$/;
    var ssnPattern = {
        3: '-',
        5: '-'
    };
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        var formatSSN = function () {
            var sTempString = ctrl.$viewValue;
            sTempString = sTempString.replace(/\-/g, '');
            var numbers = sTempString;
            var temp = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                temp += (ssnPattern[i] || '') + numbers[i];
            }
            ctrl.$viewValue = temp;

            // this is what was missing 
            scope.$apply(function(){
                 elem.val(ctrl.$viewValue);
            });
        };
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
            // test and set the validity after update.
            var valid = SSN_REGEXP.test(viewValue);
            ctrl.$setValidity('ssnValid', valid);
            return viewValue;
        });
        // This runs when we update the text field
        ctrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {

            var valid = SSN_REGEXP.test(viewValue);
            ctrl.$setValidity('ssnValid', valid);
            return viewValue;
        });
        elem.bind('blur', formatSSN);

       }
    };
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['ssnApp']);
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. More to the point, any time you want to interact with `$scope` from within a DOM event, you'll need to use `$scope.$apply` (formatSSN is fired in the onblur event), and not related to `elem.val()`.

Comment: thank you @tenthfloor, your answer was very helpful. I am running into a different issue. A 'newbie' is an understatement to describe myself.

Comment: thank you @tenthfloor, your answer was very helpful. I am running into a different issue. A 'newbie' is an understatement to describe myself. This SSn comes from a different controller containing a JSON string. for example.. see the addition to the code. I am unable to edit your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

See the additions to your fiddle below. As you will notice the unformatted values do not show up in the ng-repeater. What am i missing?

```
<form name="form" ng-repeat="contact in contacts" novalidate>
    <label>SSN</label>
       <input type="text" ng-model="contact.ssn" name="ssn" validate-ssn/>
    <br /> <span ng-show="form.ssn.$error.ssnValid">This is not valid SSN!</span>
      unformatted: {{ssn}}
</form>
```

controllerName

```
myApp.controller('ContactCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.contacts = [{
fname: "Steve",
lname: "Bob",
relationship: "Spouse",
ssn: "617-35-8006",
phone: "(777)375-8033",
   }, {
fname: "Ryan",
lname: "Hart",
relationship: "Child",
ssn: "666-22-8889",
phone: "(777)375-8033",
 }, {
fname: "Gina",
lname: "Pane",
relationship: "Child",
ssn: "997-11-6483",
phone: "(777)375-8033",
}];
   });
```